# useState hooks for published / unpublished api callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a UI that has an option to publish or unpublish an article. I use react hooks but I can't find a solution to update the view on APi callback.

SectionData returns from the API an Array of Objects:

```
0: {id: "85fdd6e0-3e38-4e42-859b-638c5770d42b", type: "section", attributes: {…}}
1: {id: "88f329dc-457c-4ec2-9c41-7b847f2c9ecb", type: "section", attributes: {…}}
2: {id: "2be4859d-79e1-429f-895f-a725f02f4912", type: "section", attributes: {…}}
3: {id: "a832aa86-9d5c-44a4-b35d-f6a8127ce203", type: "section", attributes: {…}}
```

In the code below, I'm trying to use useState in order to store the index number of the object clicked (which I should change the status from A to B (published/unpublished or viceversa)

// ListSections.js

```
const ListSections = ({ sectionData }) => {
  const [rowsData, setRowsData] = React.useState(sectionData);
  const [indexNumStatus, setIndexNumStatus] = React.useState(0);

  /*
  ** @@
  ** @@ PUBLISHED / UNPUBLISHED
  ** @@
  */
  const renderStatusButton = (status, s_id) => 
    <div onClick={() => handleStatusOnClick(status, s_id)}>
      <Status status={status} />
    </div>

  const handleStatusOnClick = (status, s_id) => {

    const changedStatus = 
      status === STATUS.PUBLISHED 
        ? STATUS.UNPUBLISHED 
        : STATUS.PUBLISHED

    const data = {
      "section": {
        "status": changedStatus  
      }
    }

    return api
      .put(URLS.CHANGE_COURSE_SECTION( course_id, s_id ), data)
      .then(({ data }) => {

        const d = data.data;

        // Maps the array to indetify the index of the updated item
        rowsData.map((r, i) => {
          if(r.id === d.id) {
            // ISSUE HERE **** issue is HERE. 
            // indexNumStatus doesn't return the correct value. Always 0
            // first, then on a second click it returns the correct index.
            // For this reason newArrayList returns the incorrect behaviour.          
            setIndexNumStatus(i); 
          }
        })

        // Inject the updated object in to 
        // the array without creating duplicates
        const newArrayList = Object.assign([...rowsData], {[indexNumStatus]: d});

        setRowsData(newArrayList);

      })
      .catch(({response}) => {
        // catch here
      });
  }

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead></TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rowsData.map((row, index) => (
            <TableRow key={index}>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.attributes.title}</TableCell>

              <TableCell align="center">
                {row.attributes.status}<br />
                {renderStatusButton(row.attributes.status, row.id)}
              </TableCell>

            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
export default ListSections;
```

Reading online people suggests using useEffect the same way as componentDidUpdate, but unfortunately, I can't use it inside a callback in the API.
If I set it up outside the API, how would I pass the index number? Maybe there is a better solution for this.

If you can please provide a snippet of code for any suggestions, that would be amazing.

Thanks for your help.
Joe

Comment: are you getting data form api on button click?

Comment: It sounds like you need both useState and useEffect. First set the index with useState on click. Then use useEffect to respond to an index change. use Effect should fire your api call. so a state change happens and then an api call is made. Is this correct?

Comment: @JoeLloyd I have 3 different API calls in the same component: Update, Delete and StatusChange (this is the one we are discussing here). All of them are triggered onClick. I am not using useEffect since I need to wait for user interaction. But based on what you say, I see that maybe the best way to do this is to create 3 different useEffect with the API call inside, and trigger useEffect with useState? (1 useState = 1 useEffect)

Comment: yes that could be an options. this about it in steps. you first want a click, like something is triggered in the state. in this clase an index selection is made. Next you want respond to that change with some api call. Seems like a perfect use case for useState useEffect. Well actually since you could be holding a bunch of data in your use state you could change from useState to useReducer and fire off actions to that reducer. Its more complex but easier to test and follows better standards.

Comment: @JoeLloyd It looks a really good solution. I'm testing it as we speak, but I've got another question: how do I pass the item ID and STATUS to the API? before it was simple but I can't do a simple props pass for the useEffect. Does it mean I have to create a useState for each prop I am passing?  beore it was this:  const handleStatusOnClick = (status, s_id, index) => { .. then the API} .. but now with useEffect, I might using useReducer for all those props.

Comment: @Joe use the index you have in state to select the correct item from the data list. Like `rowsData[indexNumStatus]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just found a solution, but please feel free to provide your input/view if you think it can be done in a better way.

**Solution**:
I didn't notice that in the render rowsData.map had already the `index`.

```
{rowsData.map((row, index) => (
.....
<TableCell align="center"> 
  {renderStatusButton(row.attributes.status, row.id, index)}
</TableCell>
```

So, instead of doing another .map inside my API callback and try to store the index number into the `indexNumStatus`:

```
BAD:
rowsData.map((r, i) => {
  if(r.id === d.id) {
    setIndexNumStatus(i);
  }
 })
```

.. I pass the index directly to the API and use it with Object.assign, here a preview:

```
Object.assign([...rowsData], {[index]: data.data});
```

As said above, please feel free to provide other options more suitable if the code can be refactored in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a value via setIndexNumStatus(i); then the value is not directly accessable in the next line. In my opinion there is no need for useState for that value.

Why you just write something like this:

```
    // Just a normal variable
    let indexNumStatus = 0; // <=====

    // Maps the array to indetify the index of the updated item
    rowsData.map((r, i) => {
      if(r.id === d.id) {        
        indexNumStatus = i; // <=====
      }
    })
```

And then later:

```
 // Here you can use your variable directly
 const newArrayList = Object.assign([...rowsData], {[indexNumStatus]: d});
 setRowsData(newArrayList);
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexander Elert, I found another solution (see above) which allows me to remove the .map in the api callback